# Ajax call returning page source code as response rather than json data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, iis

With Visual studio, everything is working perfectly on local but the issue arises when I host it on IIS. I checked under the Network tab of chrome and I am getting the response as the source code of a page and not the json string which results in an error saying "unexpected token <"

Here is the ajax method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SearchText();
});
function SearchText() {
    $("#<%= txt_supplier.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                url: "AutoComplete.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('<%= txt_supplier.ClientID %>').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d.toString());
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The web service method is as follow:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
    List<string> result = OldTurtle_BizSuite_EasyHelp2.Pages.Tickets_New.GetAutoCompleteData(username);
    return js.Serialize(result);
}
```

I feel that there is some issue with the iis setting or web.config but don't know what. please help. I am researching from last 3 days on it.

Comment: It's possible a yellow screen of death is being returned. Do you have any error logging, or have you looked at the actual content of what is being returned?

Comment: Check the json you post with firebug or any other client side dev tools. Check the address and json format.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using ? If it's 4.0 or above, I would suggest not using <%= txt_supplier.ClientID %> but instead give your textbox a ClientIDMode of 'Static'.

Comment: Agree with Jason. You can remove `dataType: "json"` and jQuery won't throw the unexpected token error, allowing you to `alert(data)` (to see the return content)

Comment: try changing return type to `List<string>` and return `result` variable directly. IIS should automatically serialize the data for you. no need for explicit serialization.

Comment: I tried everything suggested above and none of them is working for me. data that is being returned on iis is simply html and not json. Bt on Visual studio development server, all is running well and I get a proper json data as response. I feel that it has something to do with IIS setting which I am not getting.